# display a dictionary value using input

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I can import the dictionary successfully and I can get an output from the dictionary of its values but it shows me all the values and not the value that matches the input of the user.

the input is first converted to lower and then split into individual words to be referenced in the dictionary.

```
# prob_dict : dictionary

# problemlist : input lowercase and split
```

I have searched many postings but I cannot find a solution that works.

```
problemlist = problem1.split()

for problem in range(len(prob_dict)):
    if prob_dict in problemlist:
        solution = []
        solution = (prob_dict[problem])
        print('Your Solution is:', solution)
    else:
        print('could not find a solution')
```

the dictionary is:

```
prob_dict = {'wet': ['put in bag of rice to dry out'],
             'screen': ['screen will need to be replaced'],
             'charger': ['purchase new charger for our store']
             }
```

Comment: and `problem1` is what?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Please provide a MCVE (see [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: ok so the code asks 3 questions and the 3rd question is an input asking what fault you have with your device (problem1 is that input) then I set it to convert all text from the input to lower case and split it so I could compare the words in the input against keys in the dictionary and produce an answer example: user inputs I got it wet. the program then looks for a word from the sentence that matches a key in the dictionary i.e the word 'wet' and outputs the keys value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if prob_dict in problemlist` is something that will almost never happen. You wouldn't find a `dict` in a list of strings.

Instead, you should iterate through the items in the list and see if the dictionary contains a key with the item:

```
problemlist = [p.lower() for p in problem1.split()]

for problem in problemlist:
    if problem in prob_dict:
        print('Your Solution is: ', prob_dict[problem][0])
              #                                        ^ The associated string
        break # remember to break once solution is found
else:
    print('could not find a solution')
```

Comment: I totally agree with your answer, but found it weird that the OP said that they received output of all dictionary values.  I was very confused by that, wondering what the original list 'problem list' value was

Comment: *the input is first converted to lower and then split into individual words to be referenced in the dictionary.* @Eoins At one point or another one could fail to express their problem coherently. A look at the data structures used by the OP could provide a solution that will put them in the right direction. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: Thank you Moses this has been racking my brain for days, I'm new to python and I'm trying to learn it to help my daughter learn it for school.

Comment: Oh lovely. Then you will find SOpython's [What tutorial should I read?](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) useful

Comment: opps ok it works if I put in 1 word in the input for example wet but if I put in I got it wet it cannot find a solution?

Comment: @MichaelFrost The problem you describe isn't very clear

Comment: ok so the code you gave me allowed me to reference the dictionary and get the value related to the key i.e: if I input wet it came back with put in bag of rice, but if I put in the input more than 1 word i.e: I got it wet it is not picking out the key word wet and getting the value from the dictionary?

Comment: @MichaelFrost I edited the code and I tested it with `problem1 = "I got it wet"`. That should work

Comment: ok I restarted and tested again and what it is doing is outputting could not find a solution to each word until it reaches the word that matches, can it be changed to only output the one that matches?

Comment: removing the else statement stopped it

Comment: You didn't update your code. The `else` now falls directly under the `for`. See my update